# Margin/Padding of the stars in a RatingBar (or position and size)?

Tags: java, android

I try to make an custom RatingBar for my Application which has a different image for each of the 4 stars.
With the following onDraw method it works quite good on my mobile.

```
public class MyBar extends RatingBar {

    private int[] starArrayColor = { R.drawable.star_1_color, R.drawable.star_2_color, R.drawable.star_3_color, R.drawable.star_4_color };
    private int[] starArrayGrey = { R.drawable.star_1_grey, R.drawable.star_2_grey, R.drawable.star_3_grey, R.drawable.star_4_grey };

    (...)

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int stars = getNumStars();
        float rating = getRating();
        float x = 10;

        for (int i=0;i<stars;i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            Resources res = getResources();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
            paint.setDither(true);

            if ((int) rating-1 == i) {
                paint.setAlpha(255);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, starArrayColor[i]);
            } else {
                paint.setAlpha(70);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, starArrayGrey[i]);
            }

            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 75, 75, true);
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, x, 12, paint);
            x += 96;
        }
    }
}
```

But the "calculation" of the x/y position and size of the images suc*s! Its just trial and error to get the right coordinates...

How can I calculate the position/size etc. to get it working properly on every device?

In the sources of AbsSeekBar/Progressbar I have found variables called mPaddingTop, mPaddingBottom etc. Is there a way to get those values?

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap has a getWidth and getHeight function.  You can use those to calculate the size of the bitmap.  Then you can place them based on that (with whatever padding you wish to use).

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more? On which object should I call getWidth/getHeight? I would need to have the star as an object, but where do I get that from?

Comment: The Bitmap object you want to draw.  Although since you're scaling it from the original via createScaledBitmap, you know its going to be exactly 75x75, so you don't need to guess.  For the amount of padding between items-  you get to choose that too.  Best way is to pick a size that looks good in inches and multiply that by the system dpi to get the number of pixels, and use that between each element.

Comment: The size of my bitmap does not matter. And the 75x75 is what i need to calculate because it just works on my phone. But not on other devices.

Comment: Decide on a size you want in inches, and convert that to pixel widths/heights by multiplying by the dpi.  That's a way to get something that looks the same on all screens.  Pass that as the width/height in the scale function.